# Babel / Webpack not compiling Variables outside of export statement in Production build

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So i have this file:

```
const EVENT_CALENDAR_DATE_SELECTED_CHECKOUT = 'calendar/date/selected/checkout';
const EVENT_BOOKER_VALID_OCB_CLICK = 'booker/ocb/valid-click';
const EVENT_DESTINATION_SELECTED = 'booker/destination/selected';

export default {

    constructors: [ 'ready', 'events' ],

....
```

When compiling in dev mode, it results in

```
var EVENT_CALENDAR_DATE_SELECTED_CHECKOUT = 'calendar/date/selected/checkout';
var EVENT_BOOKER_VALID_OCB_CLICK = 'booker/ocb/valid-click';
var EVENT_DESTINATION_SELECTED = 'booker/destination/selected';


/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = ({
  constructors: ['ready', 'events'], 

....
```

In production however, the three variables are just missing. And i get "xx is not defined." errors.

Comment: Is anything in your code actually referencing the variables?

Comment: Yes, it does. At multiple places. I just found out that it works if I write `window.EVENT_CALENDAR_DATE_SELECTED_CHECKOUT = 'calendar/date/selected/checkout';` on declaration. But that can't be a solution.

Comment: You'll likely need to provide more-specific information. If you're not exporting them the won't exist outside that module--where *precisely* do you see the error?

Comment: I want webpack to compile the variable into the code. unfortunately, this is a legacy project and i need to get this working like this as there are way too many references to the event name variables. Do you think that this could help me? [link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject)

Comment: What do you mean by "compile the variable into the code"? If you're trying to say you want those variables to be automagically defined on `window` you can use `global.FOO_BAR = 'baz'`, although this somewhat defeats the purpose of cleaning things up.